# Switching between bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Given the linear map $$f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}^{2},\ \left(\begin{array}{c}
> x\\
> y\\
> z
> \end{array}\right)\mapsto\left(\begin{array}{c}
> 2x-y\\
> 3z
> \end{array}\right)$$
>   I want to compute the matrix of $f$ with respect to the bases $$\mathcal{B}=\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}=\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}
> 1\\
> 1\\
> 0
> \end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}
> 0\\
> 1\\
> 1
> \end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}
> 1\\
> 0\\
> 1
> \end{array}\right)\right\} $$ and $$\mathcal{B}'=\{w_{1},w_{2}\}=\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}
> 1\\
> 1
> \end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}
> 1\\
> -1
> \end{array}\right)\right\} $$
>   and then switch back to the canonical base $\mathcal{C}=\{\mathbf{e}_{1},\mathbf{e}_{2}\}$ but there are some problems in my computations which hint at possible misunderstandings. Maybe you can help:

---

First I compute the images of the vectors in $\mathcal B$: $$\begin{array} &f(v_{1})=&\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0
\end{array}\right),&\ &f(v_{2})=\left(\begin{array}{c}
-1\\
3
\end{array}\right),&\ & f(v_{3})=\left(\begin{array}{c}
2\\
3
\end{array}\right)\end{array}$$

Now I write these images as linear combinations of vectors in $\mathcal B'$: $$\begin{array}{c}
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0
\end{array}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot w_{1}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot w_{2}\stackrel{\wedge}{=}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right)\\
\ \\
\left(\begin{array}{c}
-1\\
3
\end{array}\right)=1\cdot w_{1}-2\cdot w_{2}\stackrel{\wedge}{=}\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-2
\end{array}\right)\\
\ \\
\left(\begin{array}{c}
2\\
3
\end{array}\right)=\frac{5}{2}\cdot w_{1}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot w_{2}'\stackrel{\wedge}{=}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\frac{5}{2}\\
-\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right)
\end{array}$$

In total this yields: $$A_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}}(f)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{5}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} & -2 & -\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right)$$

Now to obtain the basis transformation between $\mathcal B'$ and $\mathcal C$ I need to write the vectors of $\mathcal C$ as linear combinations of those in $\mathcal B'$: $$\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{e}_{1}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot w_{1}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot w_{2}\\
\ \\
\mathbf{e}_{2}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot w_{1}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot w_{2}
\end{array}$$ Thus I have $$T_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{C}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{array}\right)$$
But now I get $$A_{\mathcal{C}}^{\mathcal{B}}(f)=T_{\mathcal{C}}^{\mathcal{B}'}\cdot A_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}}(f)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{5}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} & -2 & -\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 2\\
0 & 3 & 3
\end{array}\right)$$ which carries the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ that shouldn't be there.Where did something go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, instead of $\frac12\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, you should work with its inverse, which happens to be $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: ah, I see! thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.